# iOS RTMP streaming library - LFLiveKit vs VideoCore lib vs alternative

Tags: ios, xcode, video, streaming, rtmp

We're using VideoCore lib for a live streaming app and started to reach certain limits e.g. project maintenance, saving the stream, portrait-oriented video formatting, external camera sources, etc.

Looking for an alternative iOS RTMP streaming library, one that is more up to date. Any tested suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

- **HaishinKit (formerly lf)** - [github.com/shogo4405/lf.swift](http://github.com/shogo4405/lf.swift) (swift, iOS/macOS, recent, well maintained) *621
- **LaiFeng iOS Live Kit** - [github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit](http://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit) (filters, well established) *2250

  > LFLiveKit IOS mobile phone push code - [github.com/chenliming777/LMLiveStreaming](http://github.com/chenliming777/LMLiveStreaming) *647
- **VideoCore** - [github.com/jgh-/VideoCore](http://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) (outdated, well established) *1343
- **KSY Live iOS SDK** - [github.com/ksvc/KSYLive_iOS](http://github.com/ksvc/KSYLive_iOS) (more filters, recent) *307

Other

- **Broadcast iOS SDK** - [cocoapods.org/pods/cineio-broadcast-ios](http://cocoapods.org/pods/cineio-broadcast-ios)
- **MediaLibDemos3x** - [github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x](http://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x) *199

---

Other (Paid)

- **Low latency GPU Streaming Library for iOS** - onlinelib·de/streaming/
  ($$?)
- **VideoStream SDK Objective-C framework for iOS** -
  videostreamsdk·com ($$$, FFMPEG license?)
- **VideoKit streaming
  framework for iOS** - iosvideokit·com ($$$+)
- **Larix Mobile Broadcasting
  SDK** - wmspanel·com/mobile_library ($$)
- **Streamaxia OpenSDK** - streamaxia·com/opensdk-ios-rtmp-library ($$)

---

> **LaiFeng iOS Live Kit** has more features, iOS only. If sharing code base between iOS and macOS **HaishinKit (LF)** seems to be a better choice, also note [Emmanouil Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343572/emmanouil-nicolas)'s answer regarding **HaishinKit lf.swift** completely written in swift and is constantly updated (!)
>   Also take a look at the project mentioned by [Emmanouil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343572/emmanouil-nicolas): [ltebean/Live](https://github.com/ltebean/Live)
>
> Testing both HaishinKit and LaiFeng iOS Live Kit libraries with Cameleon and publishing the result [here](https://github.com/Yatko/Live).

Comment: Can libraries like LFLiveKit be used to playback an RTSP h264 stream, or are they aimed at streaming (from iOS to server) and not playback?

Comment: Why all above libraries doesn't support 4K streaming even in high bandwidth network? Only 'Streamaxia OpenSDK' library mention that they're supporting 4K but still after trying their sample app with 4K streaming still it doesn't work smoothly. Highly needed suggestion on this..